# Create Class Instances from Database Query - Python

Tags: python, class

I can't figure this one out, and have spent quite a bit of time digging through questions and answers on here, but nothing seems to quite fit.

I have a class defined that creates an instance for a sensor, holding various attributes and functions.

In a database, I have the connected Sensors defined.  Right now, if there are three sensors, I have to so something like this...

```
sensor1 = Sensor(1)
sensor2 = Sensor(2)
sensor3 = Sensor(3)
```

What I would like to do is is iterate through the database, return all defined sensors (easy enough), then create the instances of the class based on that list.

I can't figure out how to take the result of a sqlite query and make it the name of the class instances...

```
con = sqlite.connect('temp.db')
with connection:
    cur = connection.cursor()
    cur.exectute('SELECT Sensor_Id FROM Sensors')
    sensors = cur.fetchall()

# I want to do something like this.  The right side of the statement is correct, but how
# can I make the left side of the assignment be dynamic based on SQL result?
for n in sensors:
    ***sensorN*** = ClassName(n[0])
```

Basically I need X number of instances of a class created, where X is the number of rows in the database table that defines each sensor.

This one has me baffled - thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you want the left side be? If it is Sensor_Id you can just use a dictionary like sensorObjs[n[0]]

Comment: Why not store them in a list? `the_sensors = [ClassName(n[0]) for n in sensors]`

Comment: The left side I want to be the instance name which is derived from the database.  Sensor1 from the database will create a new instance called sensor1 = SensorClass(), sensor2 = SensorClass(), etc.

Comment: As for storing them in a list, I guess that must be over my head.  I know how to get the database result in a list, but how can I make a class instance from each entry.  (I have the feeling I must be missing an entire concept completely!)

Comment: Can't you just use a list or dictionary? e.g.: `lst.append(Sensor(n[0]))` or something?

Comment: Storing them in a dictionary (with the names you get out of the database as the keys, and the instances you create on the LHS as the values) is going to be the most obvious, robust, easy, dare I say Pythonic? way of doing it. You could bind those names in the module if you *really* wanted to. But do you *really* need that?

Comment: @PhillipMurphy Re: storing them in a list: The code in my comment shows you exactly how to do it. The RHS is a list comprehension which creates a list containing all the instances. Alernatively you could try a dictionary comprehension: `the_sensors = {n[0]:ClassName(n[0]) for n in sensors}`

Comment: @user4122880 - OK, I think I get it... I will give this a shot and report back.  I was missing that it was a list of instances of the class (I think - LOL).

Comment: Yes, it is a list of instances of the class. But, unless you know that your sensor ids are going to be consecutive integers starting at 0, then the dictionary version is probably a better idea. I've given more fleshed out examples in the full answer I just posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
con = sqlite.connect('temp.db')
with connection:
    cur = connection.cursor()
    cur.exectute('SELECT Sensor_Id FROM Sensors')
    sensor_ids = cur.fetchall()

# I would recommend this approach
sensor = { sid : Sensor(sid) for sid in sensor_ids }
# Which allows you to access them as
sensor['Main-hall-3'], sensor['Flap-track-fairing-7'] # etc.

# If the sensor ids are integers, you might prefer
sensor = { int(sid) : Sensor(sid) for sid in sensor_ids }
# Which allows you to access them as
sensor[3], sensor[7] # etc

# If you know that the ids are going to be CONSECUTIVE INTEGERS
# STARTING AT 0, then you could do
sensor = [ Sensor(sid) for sid in sensor_ids ]
# Which allows you to access them as
sensor[0], sensor[1] # etc

# Now, if you *really* insist on having the sensors bound to names,
# then you could try
import sys
current_module = sys.modules[__name__]
for sid in sensor_ids:
    setattr(current_module, 'sensor{}'.format(sid), Sensor(sid))
# Which would allow you to access them as
sensor1, sensor2 # etc
```

One disadvantage of the last option is that it leaves you with no clear delineation between the global variables which refer to sensors and those which do not. The dictionary-based approaches (the first two suggestions) and the list-based one (the third suggestion) make it easy to access all the sensors and nothing but the sensors. For example (in the first three cases) it is easy to loop over all the sensors; in the last case it is much trickier.

Bonus: Note that I have resisted the temptation to use the name `id` (instead of `sid`) as that would have shadowed a builtin.

Comment: That worked!  And I would have NEVER figured that out on my own.  Thanks a million for the assistance!

Comment: @PhillipMurphy Just out of curiosity, which version did you go with?

Comment: I used version 1 in this post.  It makes sense once you see how it is done, but wow - how would anyone figure that one out on their own?  Thanks again!

Comment: @PhillipMurphy It's just using dictionaries to store data. That's something that should be pretty obvious to anybody who's got into the Python swing of things. The dictionary comprehension syntax is python-specific and dictionaries are a Python favourite, but the idea of holding related data in *some kind of container* should be pretty obvious to any semi-experienced programmer in any language.

Comment: It wasn't the dictionary concept that got me.  It was the for loop construct inside of the dictionary creation that got me.  I would have never figured that out.

Comment: You could have achieved your goal simply by doing `d = {}` `for sid in sensor_ids: d[sid] = Sensor(sid)`. The construct I used is called a *dictionary comprehension*. It has three siblings: *list comprehension*, *set comprehension* and the lazy *generator expression*. Once you get the hang of one of them, the other three should follow easily. Check them out, they're quite neat.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - that actually clears things up and makes more sense.